# Avro to Scala case class annotation with nested types

Tags: scala, avro

I am using Avro serialization for messages on Kafka and processing with some custom Scala code using [this annotation method](https://github.com/julianpeeters/avro-scala-macro-annotations) currently. The following is a basic schema with a nested record:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "TestMessage",
  "namespace": "",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "message", "type": "string"},
    {
      "name": "metaData",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "MetaData",
        "fields": [
          {"name": "source", "type": "string"},
          {"name": "timestamp", "type": "string"}
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And the annotation, I believe should quite simply look like:

```
@AvroTypeProvider("schema-common/TestMessage.avsc")
@AvroRecord
case class TestMessage()
```

The message itself is something like the following:

```
{"message":"hello 1",
 "metaData":{
   "source":"postman",
   "timestamp":"123456789"
 }
}
```

However when I log the TestMessage type or view the output in a Kafka consumer in the console, all I see is:

```
{"message":"hello 1"}
```

And not the subtype I added to capture MetaData.  Anything I am missing?  Let me know if I can provide further information - thanks!

Comment: Hi @derdc, sorry you ran into this. I haven't tried on a Kafka test-bench, but indeed I get an error `illegal cyclic reference involving class MetaData`. And it turns out that all the test cases with nested records are from schemas in `.avro` files instead of `.avsc` files, and apparently there is difference between them that I missed. I expect to have time to fix this in the next few days, and in the meantime you can use [Avrohugger](https://github.com/julianpeeters/avrohugger), or [avro 2 case class](http://avro2caseclass.herokuapp.com/) for a one-off (hobbyist account, may be slow to load).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should now be fixed in version `0.10.3` for Scala 2.11, and version `0.4.5` for scala 2.10

Keep in mind that for every record type in a schema, there needs to be a case class that represents it. And for Scala 2.10, the most nested classes must be defined first. A safe definition is the following:

```
@AvroTypeProvider("schema-common/TestMessage.avsc")
@AvroRecord
case class MetaData()

@AvroTypeProvider("schema-common/TestMessage.avsc")
@AvroRecord
case class TestMessage()
```

Comment: Awesome, Julian!  Just tested the update and can confirm all working.  You are a credit to the open source community